# Are a variance and mean themselves RVs?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, normal-distribution

Suppose that we have a RV $$X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2).$$

Are $\sigma^2$ and $\mu$ itself another random variables ?
**If yes** what are their mean and variance as RV ?

Comment: The answer is no.

Comment: Expectations are not random. Both $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ are defined in terms of expectations. Conditional expectations are RVs however, so you may have a scenario like conditional on $U=u$, $X\sim \mathcal{N}(u, \sigma^2)$, which is called “randomization” or “mixing” or, iirc, a Bayesian prior for $u$. Only in this manner is the mean, or any parameter of a distribution, considered as a another RV.

Comment: They can be random variables (this is called a mixture distribution). Unless stated otherwise they are constants.

Comment: Constants are, by definition, still RVs, but this is the degenerate case.

Comment: @Jethro While technically correct, I'm not sure this helps OP's confusion.

Comment: @NapD.Lover Could you please elaborate more on your "mixing" and explain how expectation $U=u$ is a RV and also explain what the acronym iirc stands for ?

Comment: no. SAMPLE variance and SAMPLE means are random variables yes, but the population variance and mean are constants

Comment: @SakethMalyala Sample/population mean/variance is irrelevant here. We are talking about a single random variable, not a (random) sample of observations out of some population.

Comment: @Math1000 yes, yes, but i wanted to make that particular in case OP might be wondering

Comment: I think it might help if you included some context for the question.  In the usual scheme of things, one would expect $\sigma, \mu$ to be constants. 
 That is, if I just saw these expressions written with no context at all I'd assume those values were constant.  But there are situations in which they are not.  Does that help at all?

Comment: @user122424 iirc means “if I recall correctly”. Here is a simple example of mixing/randomization: let $U\sim \mathcal{U}(0,1)$ be a uniform RV, and conditional on $U=u$, suppose $X\sim B(u)$, ie Bernoulli with parameter $U=u$. The unconditional mass function at $j=1$ can be found by law of total probability: $P(X=1)=\int_0^1 P(X=1|U=u)f_U(u) du$. If you haven’t studied measure theory yet you can ignore my comment about conditional expectations (its actually somewhat irrelevant now that I think about it...).

Comment: @NapD.Lover I understand your answer. But what is $f_U(u)$ there ?

Comment: @user122424 a fairly standard notation is to write $f_U(u)$ for the probability density function (PDF) of a continuous RV $U$. In particular for uniform RVs on $(a,b)$, one has $f_U(u)=1/(b-a)$ for $a<u<b$ and zero otherwise. Feel free to summarize all of the comments by myself and the other users into an answer to your own question (which is allowed by the way).

Comment: @NapD.Lover Can the integral in the r.h.s. be acutally evaulated and so compute $P(X=1)$ by this ?

Comment: @user122424 yes, it’s straightforward... substitute the expressions for the conditional PMF of $X$, $P(X=1|U=u)=u$ (since $X\sim B(u)$ conditional on $U=u$) and for the PDF of $U$, $f_U(u)=1$, to get $\int_0^1 u du$, which you should be able to compute by basic integral calculus.